# Datatable.Compute Runtime Error

Tags: c#

i want to get the maximum value from a column of data table!!

My data table has the values

```
Column1                 Date                    Column2  Column3  Column4

Electricity(KWH)    06/Jun/2013 00:00:00    99.00    43.00    56.00
Electricity(KWH)    14/Jun/2013 00:00:00    260.00   48.00    212.00
```

When i give

```
enter code here

   double a = Convert.ToDouble( dtChart.Compute("MAX(Column2)", "")); 
   variable a has value 260
```

But when using

```
         for (int i = 3; i < dtChart.Columns.Count; i++)
         {
             string a = dtChart.Columns[i].Caption; //a has value 'Column2';
             double maxYval = Convert.ToDouble(dtChart.Compute("MAX('"+a+"')",""));
         }
```

it shows exception  as //shows error as "Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier."
What to do.pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're quoting it here:

```
"MAX('"+a+"')"
```

If you're trying to get just:

```
"MAX(Column2)"
```

then you need:

```
"MAX(" + a + ")"
```

Or:

```
string.Format("MAX({0})", a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more readable and less error-prone approach, use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dtChart.AsEnumerable();
double col2Max = rows.Max(r => r.Field<double>("Column2"));
double col3Max = rows.Max(r => r.Field<double>("Column3"));
double col4Max = rows.Max(r => r.Field<double>("Column4"));
```